# Dissolve Statistics Fields and Statistic Type as Parameters in GeoProcessor

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dissolve, geoprocessing-service

I have a published service which uses a dissolve.  In arcMap the I get prompted for all the fields, including statistics fields and stat type.  I have the statistics fields marked as parameters.

However, when I publish the service to arcgis for server 10.1 all parameters show except the stats fields in the parameter list on server.  When I try to run the service through the javascript api it uses the field names and types I used just prior to publishing it.  Which, of course, works fine if I pass features with the same name.

Is it possible to publish a service with a dissolve which makes the stats fields and type a parameter that is accessible by arcgis javascript api?